# Mongodb sorting after data fetch

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting

In java drivers, I am getting records from collection into a DBCursor, then iterating them while cursor `hasNext()`.

I need to calculate a value based on fields from the fetched data, and then return the data sorted based on the new value I calculated. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: repopulate a new cursor with the list after adding the calculated field, then use cursor sort.
I can't find way to cast BasicDBList to DBCursor

Comment: There is no way to cast BasicDBList to DBCursor, look at their respective class hierarchy. What's the problem with creating a new Cursor and then using it's sort method?

Comment: the cursor contains the data from mongodb collection,
I then move it to a BasicDBList with another value, which I will later use for sorting.
How can I pass the BasicDBList with the new value to the new cursor?

Comment: Aren't you overcomplicating a bit here? Why not add your custom field and simply Collections.sort(yourList, yourComparatorForYourCustomField) on the resulting collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this guide which I found after Remon van Vliet suggested using Comparator solved my problem:

[Using Collections.sort and Comparator in Java](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/)